# jquery attr title removing is not working in Mozilla FF

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

Cold you plz look the following code,

```
<table title="Demo1">
  <tr>
  <td> <a href="" id="anch1">Test1</a> </td>
  <td> <a href="" id="anch2">Test2</a> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here the both Test1 and Test2 links displays default title "Demo1"
But i do not want the title for both links, for this functionality i am doing as follows

```
$("#anch1").removeAttr("title");
$("#anch2").removeAttr("title");
```

or

```
$("#anch1").attr("title", "");
$("#anch2").attr("title", "");
```

this code works in IE, but M FF is not working, the title is still displaying, and the table title should be there, we should not remove the table tile,
Could you plz answer..

Comment: Your link has no title attribute which can be removed.

Comment: I believe you think `title` is something which is not.

Comment: I am confused by ur request, as Chris mentioned I only see a title attribute for the table tag, so what are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to temporary clear the parent table title when hovering over the links, then restore the title when mouse leave the links. Most simple way is adding `id` to the table itself then:

```
var $table = $("#table1");
var originalTitle = $table.attr("title");
$("#anch1, #anch2").hover(function() {
    $table.attr("title", "");
}, function() {
    $table.attr("title", originalTitle);
});
```

This way you're not dependent on browser behavior.

If you want this applied to all the links in the table, change the selector from `"#anch1, #anch2"` to `$table.find("a")`.

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/4HnT6/).

Comment: Hi Shadow Wizard, It is working fin in FF, thanks, ans i would like know your up coming Blog.

Comment: It should work in all browsers, better not have browser specific code.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('table').removeAttr('title');
```

The title is applied to the table, not the anchors. Also, your table markup is malformed (you need to wrap TDs in TR), and that might confuse the selector engines.

Comment: thanks for your reply,but here the table title should be present, could you plz suggest any other way.